# jquery dataTables make my <thead> <tr> clickable but not change color on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

right now my `<thead> <tr>` is changing color to yellow, i would like to this do not.

so **First name and Place** need be clicklable so I used :  `var tr = $("tbody tr");` and works fine here in my jsfiddle sample, so the color was removed using: `var tr = $("tbody tr");`  but I don't know why is not working in my local code.

can I create a condition to make the `thead tr` not change color?

sorry I think I was not clear in my question, the click event need happen and make the tr yellow, i just don't want to make the tr in thead yellow

someone has a solution for this?

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#example').dataTable();
  dt.fnDestroy();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/crcCiZXZfm?indent=2';
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: url,
    columns: [{
      data: 'name'
    }, {
      data: 'place'
    }],"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {

       var tr = $(" tr");
      tr.one("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('row-selected');
        tr.off('click');
        //$("#example thead").find('tr').removeClass("row-selected");
      })
        }
  });

  $('#sel1').change(function() {
    if (this.value === "All") {
      table
        .columns(1)
        .search('')
        .draw();
    } else {
      table
        .columns(1)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    }
  });
});
```

css:

```
.row-selected {
  background-color: yellow !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

html:

```
<div class=" dashboard">
  <div class="col-md-8 no-padding">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 no-padding">
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option value="Filter by">Filter by country </option>
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        <option value="EUA">EUA</option>
        <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Place</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

i tried:

```
 var tr = $("tbody tr");
```

and:

```
 $("#example thead").find('tr').removeClass("row-selected");
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/6/

Comment: either remove `var tr = $(" tr");
      tr.one("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('row-selected');
        tr.off('click');
        //$("#example thead").find('tr').removeClass("row-selected");
      })
        }` this code or remove css itself

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: how about `var tr = $("tr").has('td')` as a selector so it only selects rows that have `td`s in it?

Comment: You specifically applied a CSS rule to the `.row-selected` element which is the one on the `thead`. You should change that to something in the `tbody`.

Comment: You're looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Please check this code :-***

```
 var tr = $("tbody tr");  // check change here
 tr.one("click", function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('row-selected');
 tr.off('click');
 //$("#example thead").find('tr').removeClass("row-selected");
 })
```

***Use this code for your second query what you have asked in comment:-***

```
 var tr = $("tbody tr");
 tr.on("click", function() {
     $(tr).not(this).removeClass('row-selected');
     $(this).toggleClass('row-selected');
     //tr.off('click');
     //$("#example thead").find('tr').removeClass("row-selected");
 })
```

***For your third comment:-***

```
var tr = $("tbody tr");
tr.one("click", function() {
     $('tbody tr').toggleClass('row-selected');
     tr.off('click');
     //$("#example thead").find('tr').removeClass("row-selected");
})
```

Note:- I had checked it and it's working fine.

Comment: sorry I think I was not clear in my question, the click event need happen and make the tr yellow, i just don't want to make the tr in thead yellow

Comment: works, but the problem now is: if I click in the first rown firt name and place, I cannot apply the yellow class in the other rows, any idea why?